# In openmp is omp_get_thread_num tied to the physical thread?

Tags: c++, openmp

I understand that OpenMP uses a thread pool to reuse the physical threads. My question is whether the thread number obtained from `omp_get_thread_num` is tied to the physical thread?

In other words, is the mapping `omp_get_thread_num` to `gettid` ([gettid man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html)) always the same in all parallel regions?

---

**Section 3.2.4 from the OpenMP specification ([link](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf))**

> Binding
>
> The binding thread set for an omp_get_thread_num region is the current
>   team. The binding region for an omp_get_thread_num region is the
>   innermost enclosing parallel region.
>
> Effect
>
> The omp_get_thread_num routine returns the thread number of the
>   calling thread, within the 10 team executing the parallel region to
>   which the routine region binds. The thread number is an integer
>   between 0 and one less than the value returned by omp_get_num_threads
>   , inclusive. The thread number of the master thread of the team is 0.
>   The routine returns 0 if it is called from the sequential part of a
>   program.

---

**Simple test using gettid system call**

The code below CentOS 7 using GCC,  gives me the same mapping for the two parallel for regions. But I am not sure if this is just a particular case.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::cout << "Entering region 1:" << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "num: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " => tid: " << syscall(__NR_gettid) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Entering region 2:" << std::endl;


    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "num: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " => tid: " << syscall(__NR_gettid) << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get in CentOS 7, using GCC (5.2).

```
Entering region 1:
num: 0 => tid: 625
num: 5 => tid: 630
num: 7 => tid: 632
num: 11 => tid: 636
num: 3 => tid: 628
num: 13 => tid: 638
num: 1 => tid: 626
num: 9 => tid: 634
num: 6 => tid: 631
num: 10 => tid: 635
num: 12 => tid: 637
num: 2 => tid: 627
num: 4 => tid: 629
num: 8 => tid: 633
num: 14 => tid: 639
num: 15 => tid: 640
------------------------------------------------------------
Entering region 2:
num: 4 => tid: 629
num: 12 => tid: 637
num: 15 => tid: 640
num: 5 => tid: 630
num: 8 => tid: 633
num: 13 => tid: 638
num: 0 => tid: 625
num: 9 => tid: 634
num: 1 => tid: 626
num: 6 => tid: 631
num: 3 => tid: 628
num: 7 => tid: 632
num: 10 => tid: 635
num: 11 => tid: 636
num: 2 => tid: 627
num: 14 => tid: 639
```

Compilation: `g++ toy.cpp -fopenmp`

Comment: This is a great question. But I think maybe physical ID is a red herring. What I think is more important is if the thread assigned by OpenMP maps to the same logical core between parallel regions which I think is guaranteed with binding enabled e.g. with `OMP_PROC_BIND=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Across multiple parallel regions it is not guaranteed. Here is a slightly modified example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::cout << "Entering region 1:" << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "num: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " => tid: " << syscall(__NR_gettid) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Entering region 2:" << std::endl;

    // shrinks the threadpool for libgomp
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "num: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " => tid: " << syscall(__NR_gettid) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Entering region 3:" << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "num: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " => tid: " << syscall(__NR_gettid) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output (gcc 8.2.1):

```
Entering region 1:
num: 0 => tid: 11845
num: 6 => tid: 11851
num: 3 => tid: 11848
num: 5 => tid: 11850
num: 7 => tid: 11852
num: 4 => tid: 11849
num: 2 => tid: 11847
num: 1 => tid: 11846
------------------------------------------------------------
Entering region 2:
num: 1 => tid: 11846
num: 0 => tid: 11845
------------------------------------------------------------
Entering region 3:
num: 2 => tid: 11853
num: 7 => tid: 11858
num: 5 => tid: 11856
num: 4 => tid: 11855
num: 1 => tid: 11846
num: 3 => tid: 11854
num: 0 => tid: 11845
num: 6 => tid: 11857
```

Thread pooling across parallel regions is not specified by the OpenMP standard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that between two parallel region that if you don't change the number of threads  and dynamic thread adjustment is diabled (e.g. with `omp_set_dynamic(0)`) that the threads physical ID does not change.

Comment: Okay, I think my first comment is true if the threads are bound and dynamic thread adjustment is disabled e.g. with (`OMP_PROC_BIND=true` and `OMP_DYNAMIC=false`).

Comment: Apparently there is a `proc_bind` clause now for `parallel` which I was not aware of.

Comment: I tried `OMP_PROC_BIND=true and OMP_DYNAMIC=false` with your code and it still changes the physical ID. On the other hand if I remove the second parallel region which changed the number of threads then I have not observed the thread ID to change even with those variables unset.

Comment: Okay, I think if `OMP_PROC_BIND=true and OMP_DYNAMIC=false` then the thread ID could still change but that the new thread will still be assigned to the same logical core so it will have the same memory locality.